# Create a column variable extracting values from different columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID1=c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA),ID2=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA),ID3=c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA),ID4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),ID5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
show(df)
```

I would like to create a new variable `IDchoice` using values from the `ID` variables. The new dataframe would look like this:

```
df2 <-data.frame(ID1=c(1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA),ID2=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA),ID3=c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA),ID4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),ID5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),IDchoice=c(1,3,2,NA,1,4))
show(df2)
```

This is what I tried:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,"IDchoice"] <- ifelse(df$ID1[i]=="1", 1,
                      ifelse(df$ID2[i]=="1", 2,
                      ifelse(df$ID3[i]=="1", 3,
                      ifelse(df$ID4[i]=="1", 4,
                      ifelse(df$ID5[i]=="1", 5,NA)))))
                                  }
```

But it seems to be extracting only the values from the first `ID` variable

Comment: Try `max.col(!is.na(df)) * NA^(rowSums(is.na(df))==ncol(df))`

Comment: Thanks that works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `apply`:

```
df2$IDchoice = apply(df, 1, function(x) ifelse(sum(!is.na(x))==0, NA, which(!is.na(x))))
```

**Result:**

```
  ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 IDchoice
1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA        1
2  NA  NA   1  NA  NA        3
3  NA   1  NA  NA  NA        2
4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA       NA
5   1  NA  NA  NA  NA        1
6  NA  NA  NA   1  NA        4
```